# Can we create a history track on Fusion spreadsheet?

Tags: python, pyspark, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I have a Fusion spreasheet on foundry which i want to track it's history whenever a user type something new on it or modify it's content
Can we do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your fusion sheet is [synced to a dataset](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/fusion/create-use-table-regions/), you might be able to achieve this through an upstream incremental build as described [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/create-historical-dataset/).

Something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@incremental(snapshot_inputs=['input_data'])
@transform(
    input_data=Input("/path/to/snapshot/input"),
    history=Output("/path/to/historical/dataset"),
)
def my_compute_function(input_data, history):
    input_df = input_data.dataframe()

    # note that you can also use current_timestamp() below
    # if the input will change > 1x/day
    input_df = input_df.withColumn('date', F.current_date())

    history.write_dataframe(input_df)
```

You would also need to set up a schedule such that it would build every time the upstream fusion back dataset is updated. This schedule would be set up as shown in the screenshot below. You can get more information on setting up schedules [here](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/create-schedule/#save-the-schedule).
[image]

It wouldn't capture whenever the user types but it would capture the changes made to the dataset which would be relatively close to what you want.

Comment: How can we scheldule it?

Comment: I've update my answer with an example configuration of a schedule!